# Download excel/csv file from server on angular 8 application

Tags: java, angular, excel, download

I have a scenario where the REST API call to Java from Angular returns a response object which contains a HSSF Workbook object converted to string. I need to download the excel object that is in response on angular side. Following is my code in on client side which generates csv file, but the contents are not extracted. It just displays string 'HSSF Workbook' on downloaded file. How can I get the contents of file displayed. I see we have to use blob, which I am using, but still doesn't generate file properly.

```
Client Side code:
// making a service call to download file       
 this.servicecall(params).subscribe(result => {
       if (response.hasOwnProperty('excelObject')) {
        const downloaddata = response.exceldata;
        this.downloadFile(downloaddata, 'fileName', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8');
      }
 });
     
   // method to handle download of excel file
   public downloadFile(buffer: any, fileName: string, ftype: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: ftype });
    saveAs(data, fileName);
  }
```

Comment: The REST API should NOT reply with a "Java HSSF Workbook string representation", it does not make too much sense. In that way, you'd never be able to "get the contents of file displayed".
Instead, the REST API should replay with an EXCEL FILE produced using the Java HSSF Workbook object that you're working with on server-side.
Who is producing the REST API you're using?

Comment: Update: notice that you CAN (if you need it) pass directly the Workbook Java Object (even if it is not serializable) by (for example) [coding it in Base64 as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273818/how-to-add-poi-workbook-as-a-json-element-in-java), BUT if you want to pass your excel to an Angular Client in order to show it to an user... that is NOT how to do it (you should instead pass an excel file).