# How to add POI Workbook as a json element in java

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

I  have been struggling for days in this issue. I need to add Apache poi Workbook to json object. I tried Json.org, objectmapper and gson libraries.
My approach in order to serialize it is similar for all the tested libraries,  something like:

`objectMapper.writeValue(writer, objectToSerialize);`

When I want to Write to json my Workbook object I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Not implemented yet (through reference chain: com.....[".."]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.["workbook"]->org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook["hidden"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:343)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or should I try another approach ? Thanks.

Comment: Show us a sample of your work, and what errors you faced.

Comment: A `apache poi` `Workbook` is not a file but a `Java` object. It does not implement `Serializable`. So it is not serializable. But if you want transport the `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` file via `JSON` then this file needs to be  converted into a string since `JSON` is a text format. One possibility is to `Base64` encoding the file.

Comment: Try this URL has some detail about mapping excel file to json programmatically. 
https://github.com/nullpunkt/excel-to-json/blob/master/src/main/java/net/nullpunkt/exceljson/convert/ExcelToJsonConverter.java

Comment: @AxelRichter you are right with the object being non-serializable, but there's a workaround with its write() method. I achieved converting it to base64 and getting it back from the inputstream. Some luck yeah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axel Richter's comment is right, the workbook is not serializable.

The workaround to send the `Java Object` and avoid encoding the file itself, starts by using [**`WorkBook`**](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-)'s write(OutputStream s) method:

> **`void write(java.io.OutputStream stream)`**
>
> *Write out this workbook to an Outputstream.*

Once done, we can convert the origin `OutputStream`'s bytes to a [**Base64**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) encoded string. The steps in order to **send** it are complete by now.

Now, when receiving the string, in order to read it back to a `Workbook Object`, the key is using the [`Workbook(InputStream s)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#HSSFWorkbook-java.io.InputStream-) constructor. Two of the three direct implementations of Workbook offer this constructor, while the trickiest one would need one more step. (*Info about this on the appendix below*)*.

This code is a simple test probing the whole process.

***`Workbook -> convert -> send -> receive -> revert -> Workbook`***

---

*Using the `HSSFWorkbook` implementation of `Workbook` in order to actually test it.*

### Encode - Send {*append to Json*}

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
wb.createSheet("test");

ByteArrayOutputStream binOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(binOut);  
String wbString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(binOut.toByteArray());

wb.close();
```

Now the Workbook is represented as a String [**`wbString`**], which you can append into the JSON. Also note that `ByteArray` streams don't need to be closed, but from what I've read, the Workbook should.

*Just for curiosity, the encoded base64 of this example:*

```
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
```

---

### Decode - Receive {*read from Json*}

In order to get back your  `Workbook` object, once you read the string from the Json field - *in this example `wbJsonString`*. Using the `Workbook(java.io.InputStream s)` constructor you get your original Workbook back:

```
 byte[] decodedB64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(wbJsonString); 
            
 ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedB64);
 HSSFWorkbook receivedWb = new HSSFWorkbook(bis);
 
 System.out.println(receivedWb.getSheetAt(0).getSheetName()); // --> test
```

There's another possible approach for this, using the decoder's [`wrap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap-java.io.InputStream-) method. This will return *an input stream for decoding Base64 encoded byte stream*, so you can directly pass it to the Workbook constructor:

```
InputStream b64Ins = Base64.getDecoder()
                           .wrap(new ByteArrayInputStream(wbJsonString.getBytes()));

HSSFWorkbook receivedWb = new HSSFWorkbook(b64Ins);
```

---

And that's it, you properly sent the Workbook as String and converted it back.

Note that this would also let you save/send the `Workbook` Java Objects as text, regardless of the serialization format (Json, protobuff,..)

*Even if encoding to Base64 is not needed in order to get a String representation, it will guarantee data integrity.*

---

### Appendix - implementations

The Workbook interface [offers 4 implementations](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html):

1. `HSSFWorkbook`
2. `XSSFWorkbook`
3. `SXSSFWorkbook`

   3.1 `SXSSFWorkbookWithCustomZipEntrySource`

The code above will directly work with **`HSSFWorkbook`** and **`XSSFWorkbook`** objects.

The large name's implementation is an extension of **`SXSSFWorkbook`**, so the same applies for these last two. The difference within this implementations is in the object creation, as these don't offer the constructor based on an Inputstream that the first two do.

But it does offer this one:  [`SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-). So, the only additional step would consist of calling this constructor. For example:

```
InputStream b64Ins = Base64.getDecoder()
                           .wrap(new ByteArrayInputStream(wbJsonString.getBytes()));

SXSSFWorkbook sxss = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(b64Ins));  
/* The inputstream will by itself decode the base 64 encoded bytes, 
   allowing the creation of the XSSFWorkbook. But who the hell cares about
   XSSF when you can have the KING OF kings, aka SXSSF? NO-BO-DY. So
   we just send it as argument for the SXSSFWorkbook creation and forget
   that looser. All the POI fans know SXSSF is the implementation that can 
   get you laid in a matter of seconds if shown to that co-worker...
   Yes you know what I'm talking about. Come on baby burn my fire.
   Also, Apache, "SXSSFWorkbookWithCustomZipEntrySource"? Really? Who 
   chooses your names?  */
```